# The concrete definitions of "start" and "end" in a selection range

Tags: javascript, web, dom, browser, w3c

With the [DOM Standard](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-range-end):

> For convenience, a range’s start node is its start’s node, its start offset is its start’s offset, its end node is its end’s node, and its end offset is its end’s offset.

But I can't figure out what a "start" or an "end" should be. For example (the snippet would not work on this demo):

```
    <div class="container" contenteditable="true">
        <p>a</p>
        <p>b</p>
    </div>
```

```
document.addEventListener('selectionchange', (e) => {
    const sel = window.getSelection()
    console.log(sel.anchorNode, sel.anchorOffset)
    console.log(sel.focusNode, sel.focusOffset)
    console.log('---')
})
```

If you select from the position before "a" and stop at the position before "b". You would get a result like the following (Chromium):

start: `"a" 0`

end: `<p>b</p> 0`

So why the end prefers `<p>b</p> 0` to text node `"b" 0`?

More generally, taking inline elements into consideration: Under what conditions which text/inline/block node is chosen to be the anchor/focus node? Is there a specification (for specific browsers)?

Comment: The part you quoted is only for syntactical convenience of the spec. To figure out what a "start" or an "end" should be, look at the sentence before the one you quoted: "*A [range](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-range) has two associated [boundary points](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-range-bp) — a **start** and **end**.*"

Comment: @Bergi Emm, it seems to be a conceptual definition rather than a practical method to figure out the boundary points (especially on ***which node layer is chosen***).

Comment: Yes, its the concept, not the algorithm how they are chosen